# package.json build should compile all the vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, package.json

In `package.json`I have the following command:

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --dest dist/TeamCard --name TeamCard src/components/TeamCard.vue",
```

I want to change it to be able to compile all the components that are in my components. Right now I have two other components: TeamListing, UserCard.  How can I achieve that? If I make it like:

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --dest dist/* src/components/*.vue",
```

it fails.

Comment: You may want to wrap the globs in quotes or they may be expanded in Bash and not in JavaScript.

Comment: @elclanrs tried it like `> vue-cli-service build --target lib --dest 'dist/*'  'src/components/*'` but it also did not work